# Add a Facebook Login button over a full screen Google Map

Tags: facebook, google-maps, overlay

I would like to add a facebook login button over a full screen Google Maps, as an overlay. I've found this topic: [How to make a full screen Google Map with website menu overlay?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17961669/how-to-make-a-full-screen-google-map-with-website-menu-overlay)

but when I add the required fb-root div to the HTML code, a blank block appears on the top, pushing the map below. I've tried to set display property of fb-root to none, set it with an absolute and negative positioning, but I haven't reach the goal. Here you may find my best attempt: [Facebook login over Google map](http://testinternet.altervista.org/map/)

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

Find it out! Maybe it's not a super elegant solution, but I've managed to solve by setting a negative positioning to the google map. Here follows the css for the map

```
#googlemap { width: 100%; height: 100%; position:relative; top:-32px; }
```

I've updated the code on the link I posted, hope it helps someone.